# ASP to PHP conversion, what did I do wrong?

Tags: php, asp-classic

I'm pretty new to PHP and trying to convert an asp file handling "function" to php, but for some reason the page just turns up blank when I try to run it with the PHP part (if I remove it the site fires up perfectly, without the functionallity ofcourse.

So my question is: What did I do wrong here?

```
<?php
            if (!$_GET['page'] == "")
                if (!$_GET['page'] == "gaestebog")                  

                    If (file_exists($_GET['page'] && ".html"))

                        $f=$file=fopen($_GET['page'] && ".html", r);
                        print $f;
                        fclose($file);
                    Else
                        print("Siden kunne ikke findes");
                    End If
                 elseif ($_GET['page'] == "gaestebog")
                    print "<a href='default.php?page=gaestebog'>Der kan i øjeblikket ikke oprettes nye indlæg</a><br /><br />"
                 end if

             elseif ($_GET['page'] == "")                  

                    If (file_exists("forside.html"))     

                        $f=$file=fopen("forside.html", r);
                        print $f;
                        fclose($file);
                    Else
                        print("Siden kunne ikke findes");
                    End If
             end if
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( isset($_GET['page']) )
{
    $page = $_GET['page'];

    if ( $page != "gaestebog" )
    {
        $filename = sprintf('%s.html', $page);

        if ( file_exists($filename) )
        {
            if( $handle = fopen($filename, 'r') )
            {
                echo fread($handle, filesize($filename));

                fclose($handle);
            }        
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Siden kunne ikke findes";
        }
    }
    else if ( empty($page) ) 
    {                 
         if ( file_exists("forside.html") )     
         {
             if( $handle = fopen("forside.html", 'r') )
             {
                 echo fread($handle, filesize("forside.html"));

                 fclose($handle);
             }   
         }
         else
         {
             echo "Siden kunne ikke findes";
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
<?php
if (isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page'])) {
    if ($_GET['page'] !== "gaestebog") {
        if (file_exists($_GET['page'] . ".html")) {
            $file = fopen($_GET['page'] . ".html", "r");
            $contents = fread($file, filesize($_GET['page'] . ".html"));
            echo $contents;
            fclose($file);
        } else {
            echo "Siden kunne ikke findes";
        }
    } else if ($_GET['page'] == "gaestebog") {
        echo "<a href='default.php?page=gaestebog'>Der kan i øjeblikket ikke oprettes nye indlæg</a><br /><br />";
    } else if (empty($_GET['page'])) {
        if (file_exists("forside.html")) {
            $file = fopen("forside.html", "r");
            $contents = fread($file, filesize("forside.html"));
            echo $contents;
            fclose($file);
        }
    }
    echo "Siden kunne ikke findes";
}
?>
```